# How to access folders on Desktop from Git Bash

Tags: windows, git-bash

On Windows, I have several folders(one of which is `MyFolder`) on the `Desktop` which I would like to open from Git Bash.

However, when I run `ls /c/Users/myname/Desktop` I get only:

`desktop.ini`

What is `desktop.ini` and why does it appear instead of the folders that I have on my Desktop?

Also, if I search for `MyFolder` like this:

```
find / -name `MyFolder` 2>/dev/null
```

I get no result.

Why can I not see the folders that are on `Desktop`?

Comment: The shell's desktop is a merged view of your personal desktop with the public desktop. The default locations are "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" and "%PUBLIC%\Desktop", but both folders can be relocated via the context menu properties of the respective folder.